# How can I store my last iteration in a for loop on Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, sorting, html-table

My problem is on the second iteration it always grab the "compound" value which is on the line `compound = after_tax;` what I want is grab the second iteration value as for example:

We have 36 months to compound so we have "3" 12 months as calculated on `var remaining_months = nummonth - h; var myIteration = Math.floor(remaining_months / years_in_months);   var remainIteration = remaining_months % years_in_months;`

Now, we have 3 iterations, on the 1st iteration it saves the correct compound computation but on the 2nd iteration it always grabs the `compound = after_tax` value(obviously but that is my problem lol)  any suggestions or reconstruction of code will be much appreciated.

```
<body>
    <input class="form-control" id="amount" type="number" placeholder="ex. 10000">
    <input class="form-control" id="taxrate" type="number" placeholder="ex. 25">
    <input class="form-control" id="interest" type="number" placeholder="ex. 10">
    <input class="form-control" id="months" type="number" placeholder="ex. 36">
    <input type="button" class="btn-warning btn-lg btn-block" onclick="computeResults()" value="Calculate Result">
</body>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function computeResults() {
        // Calculate
        var compound = document.getElementById('amount').value;
        var interest = document.getElementById('interest').value;
        var taxRate = document.getElementById('taxrate').value;
        var nummonth = document.getElementById('months').value;

        taxRate = taxRate/100;
        interest = 1 + (interest/100); //convert to dec

        var tableHTML = '';
        var years_in_months = 12;
        var capital = parseFloat(compound);

   
        if(nummonth > years_in_months){

            for (h = 0; h <= mValue; h++) {
                //some_code_here...
                //after_tax calculation is here
            }

            compound = after_tax;

            var remaining_months = nummonth - h;
            var myIteration = Math.floor(remaining_months / years_in_months);  
            var remainIteration = remaining_months % years_in_months;


            for ( b = 0; b < myIteration; b++) { 

                for (i = 0; i <= years_in_months; i++) {
              
                    var res = compound * (Math.pow(interest, i));
                    res = res.toFixed(0);
              
                    var interestgained = (+res * interest)-res;
                    interestgained = interestgained.toFixed(0);

                    var powint1 = compound * (Math.pow(interest, i));
           
                    powint1 = powint1.toFixed(0);
              
                    var tr = powint1 - compound;
                    var tr2 = tr - (powint1 * taxRate);

                    var ointerest = (interest - 1)*100;
                    ointerest = ointerest.toFixed(0); 


                    tableHTML = tableHTML + "<tr><td>" + months2[i] + "</td><td> " + "$"+res + "</td><td> " + ointerest + "%"+"</td><td> " + "$"+interestgained + "</td><td>"+ "$"+powint1 +"</td></tr>";
                    document.getElementById("tdisplay").innerHTML = "<thead><tr><th>Month</th><th>Amount</th><th>Interest</th><th>Total Return</th><th>Total Amount</th></tr> </thead>"+ tableHTML;
                }
                var new_powint = parseInt(powint1);
                var gross_return = new_powint - capital;
                var net_return = gross_return - (gross_return * taxRate);
                var after_tax2 = net_return + capital;

                document.getElementById("totalInterest").innerHTML = "$"+tr2.toFixed(2);
                document.getElementById("totalPayment").innerHTML = "$"+after_tax2.toFixed(2);
            
            }
            
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: @freedomn-m YES you're right, you got it the powint1, it saves the value of the first iteration it suppose to be a new value or a new data on the second iteration. Is there something that I need to do with array? or another method?

Comment: Also, please clarify on "last iteration" as it has two meanings which isn't clear from the context in your question - "previous iteration" or "final iteration".

Comment: Thanks @freedom-m, I am referring to the "powint1" which always stores the value of the first iteration on `for(i=0; i <= years_in_months; i++){....}`

Comment: @freedomn-m I did edit my post please read it again and I hope that's clear now any suggestion/help is much appreciated.

Comment: @eloyguides It would be good for help if you could post an example that can be reproduced. Many variables are missing from the function. (`mValue`, `after_tax`, `months2`) I think it was designated as a global variable. It will be helpful if you modify it to be reproducible.